# Help needed in solving this problem of Fourier Transform

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I want to know why

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos wx\sin w}{w}\,dw = \frac{\pi}{4}?$$
at x=0,given that  $$\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos wx\sin w}{w}\,dw = \frac{\pi f(x)}
{2}$$
where f(x) is
 \begin{cases}
    1       & \quad \text{if } |x|<1\\
    0  & \quad \text{if } |x|>1\\
  \end{cases}

Comment: Though the pic is very clear, it would be nice if you can write out your question here. Welcome Math.SE! Take the [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) using $LaTeX$ syntax. If you receive useful answers, consider [accepting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) one.

Comment: Note that $\cos w\sin w=\frac12\sin 2w$, and look at the link posted by **John Ma**.

Comment: I know how to prove that result posted by @John Ma

Comment: I guess you don't really mean $|x|<0$. Also , $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos wx\sin w}{w}\,dw = \frac{\pi}{4}$ is not true if $x = 0$. @PanchamAlva

Comment: yup changed it |x|<1